# Sign in user with SignInManager after OIDC authentication

Tags: asp.net-identity, openid-connect, blazor-server-side

My application is using Asp.net core Identity with local user accounts.
I have added authentication with OIDC and authentication works - I get the claims and all is fine.

My plan now is to map the response to a user account, and then sign in the user in order for all current views to work with roles just as it does today.

1: Am I approaching this the right way?

2: If yes - how can I accomplish the signin? I am inside a blazor component - here I can map the user and access SignInManager, but since I don't have a HttpContext I can't just call SignInManager.SignInAsync(...), so how do I go about actually completing the signin?

Comment: I'm in the same situation and looking for a solution. Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I managed to solve this issue.
In _HostAuth.cshtml.cs I do this:

```
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (!SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                if (!await MySignInMethod())
                {
                    Redirect("someUsefulPlace");
                }
            }
        }
```

Then MySignInMethod looks like this:

```
    private async Task<bool> TrySignInWithSsn()
    {
        var myClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "MyClaimName");
        if (myClaim != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myClaim.Value))
        {
            var myClaimValue = myClaim.Value;
            await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
            var user = await ApplicationUserRepository.GetUserByClaimValue(myClaimValue, new CancellationTokenSource().Token);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It fishes out the claim value I need to fetch the User from the database (in my case a social security number) and then signs the user in. Works like a charm!